# How to detect presence of namespace prefixes in SOAP messages

Tags: java, xpath, soap

I am developing a java application that accepts SOAP/HTTP Web Service requests from many diverse remote clients.

I have no control over these clients and how they construct their SOAP requests.

I have to extract multiple key XML elements and their related data from these SOAP request messages.

Some clients use namespace prefixes on the all the tags while other clients do not.

Is there any way I can detect the presence of namespace prefixes within each SOAP Request message (or sub document) I receive?

Comment: actually it should not matter, as long as the document is valid.

Comment: Please give an example of the types of documents you need to accept. The first couple of lines of each should be sufficient. Normally, the namespace **prefixes** should not matter, but all SOAP requests must be in the namespaces specified by the SOAP standards. So you can likewise ignore the prefixes and just look for elements in the correct namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already commented, namespace prefixes do not matter:

> In XML with namespaces, an element or attribute name are qualified names, that is, they consist of a namespace and a local name part, with the namespace identified by a prefix, separated by a colon from the local name. If the prefix is empty, there is no colon and the name is said to be in the default namespace, if the prefix is non-empty, the name is said to be in the namespace according to its in-scope namespace binding (the attribute-like declarations starting with `xmlns`).

The prefix itself has no bearing on the identification of the name. It is the namespace and the local part that are important. All the following example have the same qualified name for `root` and `envelope`, even though they have different prefixes:

```
<root>
  <envelope xmlns="urn:envelopes" />
</root>

<root xmlns:env="urn:envelopes">
  <env:envelope/>
</root>

<root xmlns:soap="urn:envelopes">
  <soap:envelope xmlns="urn:envelopes" />
</root>

<root xmlns:soap="urn:envelopes">
  <envelope xmlns="urn:envelopes" />
</root>

<root xmlns:soap="urn:envelopes">
  <foobar:envelope xmlns:foobar="urn:envelopes" />
</root>
```

While it is possible to write an XPath expression that is prefix-dependent, this is not recommended and will break as soon as a valid document arrives that uses a different prefix.

> Is there any way I can detect the presence of namespace prefixes within each SOAP Request message (or sub document) I receive?

Sometimes, however, it is convenient to know the namespaces used in a document. Getting the prefixes will not help with that, but it can sometimes help with analyzing errors.

If you can use XPath 2.0, there's a simple one-liner you can use to find all the namespaces in the document:

```
distinct-values((//* | @*)/in-scope-prefixes(.))
```

While this will answer your question, namespace redeclaration will result in one prefix being returned that is in fact bound to several namespaces. To get all the unique names, that is prefix + colon + local-name, you can use:

```
distinct-values((//* | @*)/name(.))
```

To get this same information with XPath 1.0 is a little bit dramatic, as there is no `distinct-values` and the rh-side of a path expression cannot return a non-node item. Instead, I would recommend to use a little bit of XSLT 1.0, easy enough to implement with Java (or alternatively, select all nodes and iterate over them using plain Java):

```
<xsl:template match="* | @*">
    <xsl:if test="not(self::*)">@</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    <xsl:if test="namespace-uri()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' uses &quot;', namespace-uri(), '&quot;')" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @*" />
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you really only want the prefixes, this dumps the names with prefixes and the associated namespaces:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), ':')] | @*[contains(name(), ':')]">
    <xsl:if test="not(self::*)">@</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' uses &quot;', namespace-uri(), '&quot;')" />
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" ><xsl:apply-templates select="* | @*"/></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text() | @*" />
```